# Pretty-printing comma-separated list of strings in ant

Tags: ant, pretty-print

I have a comma-separated string in an ant property, like this:

```
<property name="prop" value="a,b,c"/>
```

I would like to be able to print or log it like this:

```
Line 1: a
Line 2: b
Line 3: c
```

Doesn't sound like it should be too difficult, but I cannot figure out which ant components I should be putting together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sample using [Ant-Contrib Tasks](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

<target name="test_split">
    <property name="prop" value="a,b,c"/>
    <for list="${prop}" param="letter">
        <sequential>
            <echo>@{letter}</echo>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

The output is:

> a 
>   b 
>   c

Another solution from [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200408.mbox/%3C879A5AD5DD0ED511891F0003473A9B560E23F4EE@Z011004%3E):

```
<scriptdef name="split" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="value"/>
    <attribute name="delimiter"/>
    <attribute name="prefix"/>
    <![CDATA[
         values = attributes.get("value").split(attributes.get("delimiter"));
         for(i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
             project.setNewProperty(attributes.get("prefix")+i, values[i]);
         }
     ]]>
</scriptdef>

<target name="test_split2">
    <property name="prop" value="a,b,c"/>
    <property name="prefix_str" value="Line_"/>
    <split value="${prop}" delimiter="," prefix="${prefix_str}"/>
    <echoproperties prefix="${prefix_str}"/>
</target>
```

The output is:

> Ant properties
>   Tue Nov 22 17:12:55 2011
>   Line_0=a
>   Line_1=b
>   Line_2=c

Comment: Nice. I'm already using ant-contrib, so the `for` solution is by far the shortest and easiest to read.

Comment: How can i use the @{letter} globally! or i want to use this @{letter} some were else in another target...Is there any way.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by using [loadresource](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadresource.html) specifying the property value as a [string](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#string) resource. Now you can use a [replaceregex](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex) filter to convert comma to newline.

```
<project default="test">

  <property name="prop" value="a,b,c"/>

  <target name="test">
    <loadresource property="prop.fmt">
      <string value="${prop}"/>
      <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="," replace="${line.separator}" flags="g"/>
        </tokenfilter>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>
    <echo message="${prop.fmt}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

The output is:

```
test:
     [echo] a
     [echo] b
     [echo] c
```

Comment: Nice. The `for` solution seems better suited in this case though, but this could be also be useful.